# Log4net client to log4j server

Tags: c#, java, logging, log4j, log4net

I am a little new to programming and i recently developed a client to server C# application using log4net on both side.

Is there a way to send and receive logs using log4net (C#) on the client side with a log4j (Java) on the server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log4Net and Log4J can forward [logs on the network through UDP](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.UdpAppender.html), but there is no way to aggregate the logs through Log4X since the framework doesn't handle listening for messages on the network.

However it is possible to use some [tools](http://udplogviewer.codeplex.com/) to aggregate network logs coming from different sources so you can setup both your applications to send logs to a machine hosting the tool that will handle the messages